# Где можно применить рекурсию в данной программе? Может быть в сортировке как то можно реализовать?

Tags: java, рекурсия

Есть отсортированный массив размерностью `N`, есть число которое надо добавить в массив. Отсортированный массив размерностью `N+1` получается. Получится ли рекурсия?
Вот реализация в программе, один метод берет из неотсортированного массива значение по индексу, бросает в отсортированный, получаем на выходе отсортированный массив, а второе метод берет числовое значение. Возможна ли где то здесь рекурсия? Может быть в сортировке?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TaskMentor2 {
//    public static ArrayList<Integer> insertToRightPlace(int valueToAdd, ArrayList<Integer> sortedList) {
//        sortedList.add(valueToAdd);
//        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size() - 1; i++) {
//            for (int j = i + 1; j < sortedList.size(); j++) {
//                if (sortedList.get(i) < sortedList.get(j)) {
//                    int max = sortedList.get(i);
//                    sortedList.set(i, sortedList.get(j));
//                    sortedList.set(j, max);
//                }
//            }
//        }
//        return sortedList;
//    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> insertToRightPlaceByIndex(int indexOfUnsortedArray, ArrayList<Integer> sortedList) {
        sortedList.add(sortedList.get(indexOfUnsortedArray));
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sortedList.size(); j++) {
                if (sortedList.get(i) < sortedList.get(j)) {
                    int max = sortedList.get(i);
                    sortedList.set(i, sortedList.get(j));
                    sortedList.set(j, max);
                }
            }
        }
        return sortedList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        sortedList.add(10);
        sortedList.add(7);
        sortedList.add(9);
        sortedList.add(11);
//        ArrayList<Integer> sortedListPlusValue = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//        sortedListPlusValue = TaskMentor2.insertToRightPlace(55, sortedList);
//        System.out.println(sortedListPlusValue);
        ArrayList<Integer> sortedListPlusValueByIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        sortedListPlusValueByIndex = TaskMentor2.insertToRightPlaceByIndex(1, sortedList);
        System.out.println(sortedListPlusValueByIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос совершенно непонятен.

Comment: У вас N рублей в кармамне. Вы нашли ещё один рубль. Теперь у вас N+1 рублей. Это не имеет ничего обзщего с рекурсией.

Answer (score 1):

[Рекурсия в программировании](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%92_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8) - это функция, которая вызывает саму себя. Пример:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
        recursion(arr, 0); // вывод: 1 2 3
    }

    public static void recursion(int[] arr, int index) {
        System.out.println(arr[index]);
        if (index < arr.length - 1) {
            recursion(arr, ++index);
        }
    }
}
```